# Scheduler configurations in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have 100 thread groups under a single test plan.And I want to run my load test for particular date and time for example 2018/03/20 12:55:15 to 2018/03/20 13:55:15 for all of my thread groups.So it is not feasible to manually copy paste same date in all thread group which is time consuming.
So is there any way so that I can automate start time and end time in the scheduler configurations such that in a single process i can run all the thread groups for a particular time interval???

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it with the help of [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool, it naturally supports JMeter .jmx scripts and you can amend properties in them (including Thread Groups start time) using simple [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) syntax.

Example configuration will look like:

```
---
execution:
  scenario:
    script: test.jmx
    modifications:
      set-prop:
        "Thread Group>ThreadGroup.start_time" : 1521985369558
```

Change `1521985369558` to the desired Thread Group start time (in form of milliseconds since start of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time))

References:

- [Modifications for Existing Scripts](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: Can we achieve it by using only Jmeter version 3.1 tool only.Is there any way that i can use some variable for start time and end time and defining some value for that in the property files.Please suggest